# Ubuntu 20.04, Bluetooth headphone connected, but no sound and doesn't appear on output device

Tags: audio, bluetooth, ubuntu-20.04

I updated from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 today and the biggest issue I'm having is that my Bluetooth headphones can connect just fine, but it doesn't work and when I go into sound settings and looked into the output devices options the Bluetooth headphones weren't there as an option.

Comment: I have the same problem with Ubuntu 22.04